# PHP error on port 8080

Tags: php

I have Apaache installed and configured to listen to port 8080
Have used PHP runner and the out put in the htdocs folder under /apache24/htdocs

When i browse the website locahost:8085 it works fine 
but when i browse the website localhost:8080 it shows the below error

I think all that happened after installing and uninstalling the IIS

Any idea how to fix that?!

Regards

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; facebookWrapper has a
>   deprecated constructor in C:\Apache24\htdocs\include\phpfunctions.php
>   on line 24
>
> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; class_GlobalEvents has a
>   deprecated constructor in C:\Apache24\htdocs\include\events.php on
>   line 36
>
> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; TLayout has a deprecated
>   constructor in C:\Apache24\htdocs\classes\layout.php on line 3
>
> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; ConnectionManager has a
>   deprecated constructor in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\connections\ConnectionManager.php on line 2
>
> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; Connection has a deprecated
>   constructor in C:\Apache24\htdocs\connections\Connection.php on line 2
>
> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be
>   constructors in a future version of PHP; MySQLiConnection has a
>   deprecated constructor in
>   C:\Apache24\htdocs\connections\MySQLiConnection.php on line 2

Comment: I have deleted all files in the htdocs folder and created the project again to make sure there are no file duplication but still can't understand why it would browse normally on port 8085 and shows error on port 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting those warnings because the PHP code you are executing probably is a bit outdated and/or you may be using a newer version of PHP.

In the old days a class constructor would be defined by giving a method the same name as the class. Later on this was changed constructors always have the name `__construct`.

The quick-and-dirty way to get rid of these errors is to change the error_reporting setting in your `php.ini` file. To something like `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED` or possibly `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE`, but be warned. With newer versions of PHP your code might stop working all together.

This will disable all Deprecated warnings and all notices for the second option.

The right way to fix this is to update all the offending code. To do this you will have to change the class constructor names, the methods with the same name as the class, to __construct.